# Why I need to provide the location object to Switch component to make exit animation work?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, framer-motion

I am using framer-motion and react-router-dom in my app.
I wanted to animate some route transitions and I was failing. The route components were being unmounted directly and no exit animation was being executed despite I was using the `AnimatePresence` component from framer. After checking some tutorials I noticed that many of the examples were providing the location object to the Switch component. I tried it and indeed it worked, the exit animations were being executed. So for example, on this piece of code:

```js
const location = useLocation()
// ...
<AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
        <Switch location={location} key={location.pathname}>
          <Route path="/names/boy">
            <motion.div
              variants={tabAnimations}
              initial="boy"
              animate="present"
              exit="boy"
            >
              <GenderList gender="M" />
            </motion.div>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/names/girl">
            <motion.div
              variants={tabAnimations}
              initial="girl"
              animate="present"
              exit="girl"
            >
              <GenderList gender="F" />
            </motion.div>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
</AnimatePresence>
```

If I change the Switch portion to this `<Switch key={location.pathname}>` it will stop tracking the child nodes properly and it will not execute exit animations. Why is this?
I checked the [react-router-dom docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch/location-object) and I didn't found anything that explains this. It only says that the location component refers what location object to use, and it fallbacks to use the browser one, but that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [react-router transition tutorial](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/animated-transitions) for animated transitions.

There is a comment in their demo that explains why:

```
<TransitionGroup>
  {/*
    This is no different than other usage of
    <CSSTransition>, just make sure to pass
    `location` to `Switch` so it can match
    the old location as it animates out.
  */}
  <CSSTransition
    key={location.key}
    classNames="fade"
    timeout={300}
  >
    <Switch location={location}>
      <Route path="/hsl/:h/:s/:l" children={<HSL />} />
      <Route path="/rgb/:r/:g/:b" children={<RGB />} />
    </Switch>
  </CSSTransition>
</TransitionGroup>
```

You need to pass the *entire* `location` object so it can diff the locations during transitions.

See [location](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/location):

> Locations represent where the app is now, where you ***want it to go***, or
> even ***where it was***. It looks like this:
>
> ```
> {
>   key: 'ac3df4', // not with HashHistory!
>   pathname: '/somewhere',
>   search: '?some=search-string',
>   hash: '#howdy',
>   state: {
>     [userDefined]: true
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still don't understand how Switch uses the location object to make this happen and why It can not be done with the browser location. The animation component is completely external to the Switch, so I don't see how anything the switch does internally can affect their parent wrappers.